# A command with the name/alias "${command.name}" is already registered

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, commando

I am using Node.js Discord.js-commando, I try to run my code but this comes up please tell me if you are having the same error or have a fix. The code under is from the index.js for your help. Please reply to this message and tell me if you know ut

```
C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:129
                        throw new Error(`A command with the name/alias "${command.name}" is already registered.`);
                        ^

Error: A command with the name/alias "help" is already registered.
    at CommandoRegistry.registerCommand (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:129:10)
    at CommandoRegistry.registerCommands (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:176:9)
    at CommandoRegistry.registerCommandsIn (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:200:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover Now\index.js:67:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

This is my code/ command handler in my index.js I have 5 categories each with their own name. Please rply with a a answer if u have one

```
client.registry
  .registerDefaultTypes()
  .registerGroups([
    ["fun", "Fun Commands"],
    ["moderation", "Moderation Commands"],
    ["special", "Special Commands"],
    ["misc", "Misc Commands"],
    ["music", "Music Commands"]
  ])
  .registerDefaultGroups()
  .registerDefaultCommands()
  .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, "commands"));
```

Comment: Did you read the error? It tells you what command. What code are you running that's causing this error? Please read this page in its entirety https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you have in your post title is not the error. That is the code that creates the error. The error itself is just below it in the pasted output.

Comment: Discord.js-commando already got a `help` command registered, you can either disable that command or change your custom command name from `help` to something else.